# Azure Web App - Error on Dashboard "Azure Web App Service Memory Exhausted"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-service-plan

I have created New Azure Web App Service, with "S2" service plan, and associated this with new Resource Group. I have not yet assigned / deployed any application to this Web App service.

As soon the web app service is created, it starts showing up "Web App Service Memory Exhausted".

And to the surprise, after deleting the web app service, the resource group and service plan, if I create the same web app service, it works fine.

I could not get the reason for this memory usage and error title in azure.

Comment: you should raise ticket to Microsoft, maybe instance didn't create properly that time. also using KUDO you can check memory usage of that app service

Comment: Do you create a new service plan? If you use the existing one, there may be serial web apps on it. Then it shows the fact.

Comment: yes, had created new service plan as well. The investigation log was always healthy. Maybe instance didn't create properly that time.